# sql max sub of Columns

Tags: sql, oracle

First I did:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
  id INTEGER not null,
  capital_loss INTEGER, 
  capital_gain INTEGER, 
  salary INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);
```

I want to get the id and the salary of one row such that:

```
max(capital_gain-capital_loss) and salary =50
```

Comment: What if there are multiple rows (not only one) that has the same Max(capital_gain-capital_loss)?

Comment: And what is the query you have tried?

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: if there is multiple just return one of them... and I tried: SELECT salary, MAX(capital_gain - capital_loss) AS max FROM Persons "

Comment: I am using Oracle JDBC Driver in java

Comment: `SELECT id, salary FROM Persons WHERE salary=50 ORDER BY (capital_gain - capital_loss) DESC LIMIT 1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this

```
select id, salary, max(capital_gain - capital_loss)
from Persons 
where salary = 50
group by id, salary
```

Comment: @Yael do you have a person with the salary of 50? Try it without the where statement

Comment: yes I have, I forgot to answer I am using sql not MySQL. and now it returning all the rows Existing after doing capital_gain - capital_loss, and not the max of them. for example 666 50 8614 
,705 50 25236 
,706 50 0 
,726 50 0 
,940 50 0 . which id  705 is the max (25236 )

Comment: okay I added another SELECT before and now its working. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Having on mind your conditions (no matter which row is returned from all of maximum ones), and if you are using mysql:

```
SELECT id, salary FROM Persons
WHERE salary=50
ORDER BY (capital_gain - capital_loss) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Please state clearly in your question which database engine you are using.
My answer was clearly mysql-oriented (as stated in the answer).

Comment: I am using Oracle JDBC Driver in java. so Its sql not mysql